# Completely finish the actitvity

Tags: android

In made the android app. I installed it in my mobile. When I press back button on my mobile it comes out of the app. But it is running in the background. So, how can I finish the activity completely? I wrote the code `onkeydown` event also. Even it is running in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call Activity.finish() to kill of an activity completely.

Be aware that this it not something your should normally do, as Android really want to manage the activity life cycle for you, as mentioned by Sheikh Aman.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the `onStop()` method on your activity and in call the `finish()` method from it. Don't forget to call `super.onStop()` at the beginning of the `onStop()` method.
As far as I know it's not running on the background, android saves the state of the activity and when it comes back, it restores your activity with the same state it was.

Comment: Try this! Try LocationManager.removeUpdates() in onStop

Comment: Also read the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle which describes why you shouldn't bother. 
NB: Your finished application will still be seen in the "process list" (which you get when holding down the home button).

Answer (score 0):

Hi see the following link in that also same question is available.[Finish the android application completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732184/how-to-finish-an-android-application/4732249#4732249)

Answer (score 0):

I will keep running in the background. Android decides when to kill your activity.

By the way, How do you ensure that it is running and "working" (is not frozen) ??

Comment: my app get the current location.It shows the status of gps on toast.When i enable the GPS it shows GPS enabled on toast.So when i press back button it comes out and then when i disable the GPS.It shows GPS Disabled on toast.That is my problem.

Comment: It maybe because your device says so, but not the app!! Just a wild guess. which device you have?

Comment: My device is not saying that.My app says that bcoz i wrote the code for showing status and my device is Samsung G3.

Comment: Then stop watching for GPS location when your activity's onStop() method is called.

Comment: @Dev.Android: As @hackbod says, you need to properly manage your activity lifecycle and respond to onStop(), but also onPause(), and onResume()

Answer (score 0):

In your `onKeyDown()` handler you should add this:

```
finish();
```

This causes the activity to be closed.

Answer (score -1):

Call this:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

It's odd, but only this call guarantees that you will kill your application. Due to specific Android life-cycling neither finish() nor any other methods doesn't kill application.