# Wrong activity started on pressing home button

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem which took my 2 days but i m unable to solve it... The problem is, i have more than 1 activities in my application.... lets say i have Activity A and B and a receiver C.

B is always started from C. A is always the starter activity (Authentication). Now the problem is when i exit from the application, C still is active and receiving... (i also want it to be like this).... As application is not running and C starts the activity B based on some incoming event, now i press back button and activity B destroys now if i long press HOME button and start the application it starts the activity B but i want that A should be the starting activity.... 
Any one can help...

plz ask if you dont understand the problem.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

use following link code  [adjust the activity status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732184/how-to-finish-an-android-application/4732249#4732249)

Comment: in that link every acity stating code is provided.see that link once

Comment: User333, i tried the code "starting the activity" but not helpful, i also tried the "android:cleartaskonlaunch" its also not working.... are you sure you understand the problem correctly... the thing is, i am looking some other posts saying approx the same problem and answer is "android:cleartaskonlaunch" but it is not working in my case.... i dont know why...