# Sending a running application to background programmatically

Tags: android

Is it possible to send a activity into background programmatically in android?

I am creating a prank application that plays funny sounds after a specified time (input by the user). And I don't want the application to be visible when playing that sound and also the display should be dark.

Comment: can you give more details ? Why you want to send in background?

Comment: I am creating a prank application that plays funny sounds after a specified time (input by the user). And i don't want the application to be visible when playing that sound and also the display should be dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe play the sound from a service instead?

Answer (score 28):

Yes.

You can use either:

```
boolean sentAppToBackground = moveTaskToBack(true);

if(!sentAppToBackground){
  Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
  this.startActivity(i);
}
```

More information here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack(boolean)

Or simply:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
this.startActivity(i);
```

According to Romain Guy a Android Framework Engineer, "You cannot simulate a press on the Home key.". So beware...

Check: http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2010-03/msg01887.html

Updated this answer according to: [moveTaskToBack(true) returns false always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473537/movetasktobacktrue-returns-false-always)

Comment: does'nt work as expected for me here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473537/movetasktobacktrue-returns-false-always

Answer (score 11):

This function ultimately works for you

```
moveTaskToBack(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer by @ns476, the reason you should play it from a service is that any `Activity` that is no longer in the foreground can be killed at any time by the OS.  Please review the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles).