# How to write code to hide current sencha touch app?

Tags: android, html, sencha-touch-2

There is one case that I need to click one button that does the same thing like the 'home' button, just to hide the app, not exit the app.

Could you tell me how to write method to simulate the 'home' button in android and ios?

thanks.

Comment: This is just not possible in Android. Whether you are using sencha touch or native android code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944562/sending-a-running-application-to-background-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere and it seems like it is not possible for now.

Comment: there is a plugin called backashome.