# Navigate to menu on back button press

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm navigating from:

- `Main activity` to `Activity 2`
- `Activity 2` to `Activity 3`
- `Activity 3` to `Activity 4`

through `Intent`.

I've also created the menu so that user can directly navigate from `Activity 4` to `Main activity`. 
But after navigating from `Activity 4` to `Main activity` by using menu, when I press back, it takes me to `Activity 3` rather than **exiting the application**.

I tried:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    MainActivity.this.finish();
}
```

But no gain. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please finish current activity go to another activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Stack Overflow indeed Rocks!

Comment: If you got the answer means, Don't forget to mark as accept

Comment: I think that was answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732184/how-to-finish-an-android-application?rq=1

Comment: in `manifest.xml` in above link, why it is `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>` instead of `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try this code when you navigate from 4th Activity to Main Activity.

```
Intent inMain=new Intent(Activity4.this, MainActivity.class);
inMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(inMain);
```

Note:

This code in your case, clears the previous activities and launches the main activity with no activity in the backstack.

Answer (score 3):

You can set flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to finish all the intermediate activities and your called activity will come to top of the activity stack.

Answer (score 2):

use the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP with your intent. For more detail -

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Answer (score 1):

call startActivity Method using clear top flag

```
   startActivity(new Intent(this, UI.class)
  .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider your "[back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)" more closely.

What is happening exactly is, your back stack gets populated as follows:

```
Main activity -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> Activity 4
```

Then from `Activity 4` you launch your `Main Activity`. So your stack becomes:

```
Main activity -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> Main Activity
```

Hence, when you press back, you land up in `Activity 3`.

Solution:

Either call `finish()` on every `Activity` when you navigate away from them. Or use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to clear all intermediate `Activities`.

More about [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Answer (score 1):

When you go back to the `MainActivity` you need to use the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` on your `Intent`. This is an example of a `goHome` method that you can used in your `Activity`:

```
public void goHome ()
{
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent();
    homeIntent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
    homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(homeIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In activity 2 and 3, after calling `startActivity(intent)`, call `this.finish()`. This will also be one solution.

Comment: no, it'll not work in my case as if I want to get back to 2 from 3, I can't navigate

Answer (score 0):

Finish previous activity when you are go to the next activity means write `finish();` after `startactivity(intent);` and write below code for start first activity from fourth activity's button click event.

```
Intent in1=new Intent(Act4.this, Act1.class);
startActivity(in1);
finish();
```

Comment: no, it'll not work in my case as if I want to get back to 2 from 3, I can't navigate

Comment: @GAMA you can navigate to activity3 to activity2 using intent.

Comment: no, not using intent. i'm talking about going to act 3 from act 2 by using back button.

Comment: @GAMA Using this code you are going to act3 to act2, Intent in1=new Intent(Act3.this, Act2.class); startActivity(in1); finish();

Comment: NO, i'm not navigating from 3 to 2 by code. That should be taken care by back button and hence I'm not using `finish()`