# why does android restart my application after a call to System.exit(0)

Tags: android

I have a class which extends Application. In its onCreate() I have:

```
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            new UncaughtExceptionHandler()
            {               
                 @Override
                 public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
                 {
                      System.exit(0);
                 }
             });
```

expecting my app to go off forever. But after System.exit(0) is called, android restarts my application as if I've launched it myself. Why?

By the way, do you know any way to show an **AlertDialog** notifying the user of the uncaught exception?

Comment: why you're calling System.exit? I thing be a better idea uses the finish method.

Comment: finish() is a method of Activity. Like I said, I'm handling uncaught exceptions in my Application instance. So finish() is simply impossible.

Comment: Why aren't you just letting uncaught exceptions kill the app like normal?

Comment: Because I'm going to ask the user if they want a few log files to be sent to me.

Comment: Most likely your app isn't restarting - the current activity is killed and you are seeing the next one on the activity stack. Look at integrating ACRA into your app - it handles crashes elegantly and allows crash reports to be sent to you in whatever manner you wish.

Comment: You don't need the exit because that is already taken care of, you should just implement the Log storing and sending, implement ACRA for crash reports! EDIT: beat me to it ;)

Comment: Setting exception handler on current thread only doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Comment: try it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732184/how-to-finish-an-android-application

Comment: But when I delete that line (System.exit(0)) the app freezes in the last state it was. Nothing happens for ages.

Comment: #Grzegorz: I cannot see your point. Then how can I handle UNCAUGHT exceptions? Isn't that what setUncaughtExceptionHandler has been designed for?

Comment: #NigelK: No, onStart() was called indicating it's a new start.

Answer (score -1):

You can not use `System.exit()` in Android, it causes undesired behavior as you have found.  If you must terminate an activity, use `finish()` instead and let Android clean it up.

Comment: finish() is a method of Activity. Like I said, I'm handling uncaught exceptions in my Application instance. So finish() is simply impossible.

Comment: By the way, all I want to do is to show the user an AlertDialogue and ask them if I'm allowed to email a few log files or not. Any idea?

Comment: When your app crashes, Android asks the user if they want to report it, which sends a bug report with logs to your developer console.  What do you want to accomplish that isn't covered by that?

Comment: #Ralgha: The only thing I see is "unfortunately ... is closing unexpectedly".

Comment: If you're installing over ADB you won't see it, you only get that option if it's installed via the Play Store.