# Android close an application

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-studio

I've read there are a lot of ways to close an application, so I would like to know if this way is correct or there are defects

**main_activity.java**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    .....
    .....
    else if (id == R.id.exit) {
        onDestroy();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    System.exit(0);
    super.onDestroy();
    finish();
}
```

Is this conceptually correct?

Comment: Why should you close an app?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732184/how-to-finish-an-android-application

Comment: FYI, you probably should not have an exit option in your app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to exit an app is using

```
finishActivity();
```

You don't want to kill the whole process, it is not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

To close your app, this pinch of code will help you do the job.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

[Android How to programmatically close an app..](http://blog.kibotu.net/java/android-programmatically-close-app-by-pressing-back-button-properly)

But you may want to know that I have never seen this approach in use anywhere. Even apps from certified developers do not try to close and remove themselves from processes. What you can really do and preferred is finishing all the running activities and services and hence allow user to kill apps from recent apps himself (default behaviour of any app).

This functions closes all activities but not app -

```
finishAffinity(); // API 16
```

Or you can call

```
finish();
```

everytime you end an activity.

These do not close Services to best of my knowledge and you programmatically have to stop running Services.

Cheers!